# Trouble adding season column based on a datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I'm trying to finish my workproject but I'm getting stuck at a certain point.

Part of the dataframe I have is this:

| year_month | year | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2007-01 | 2007 | 1 |
| 2009-07 | 2009 | 7 |
| 2010-03 | 2010 | 3 |

However, I want to add the column "season". I'm illustrating soccer seasons and the season column needs to illustrate what season the players plays. So if month is equal or smaller than 3, the "season" column needs to correspond with ((year-1), "/", year) and if larger with (year, "/", (year + 1)).
The table should look like this:

| year_month | year | month | season |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2007-01 | 2007 | 1 | 2006/2007 |
| 2009-07 | 2009 | 7 | 2009/2010 |
| 2010-03 | 2010 | 3 | 2009/2010 |

Hopefully someone else can help me with this problem.

Here is the code to create the first Table:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'year_month':["2007-01", "2009-07", "2010-03"],
                  'year':[2007, 2009, 2010],
                  'month':[1, 7, 3]})

# convert the 'Date' columns to datetime format
df['year_month']= pd.to_datetime(df['year_month'])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to specify the condition and get corresponding strings according to `True` / `False` of the condition, as follows:

```
df['season'] = np.where(df['month'] <= 3, 
                        (df['year'] - 1).astype(str) + '/' + df['year'].astype(str), 
                        df['year'].astype(str) + '/' + (df['year'] + 1).astype(str))
```

Result:

```
  year_month  year  month     season
0 2007-01-01  2007      1  2006/2007
1 2009-07-01  2009      7  2009/2010
2 2010-03-01  2010      3  2009/2010
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lambda function with conditionals and `axis=1` to apply it to each row. Using `f-Strings` reduces the code needed to transform values from the `year` column into strings as needed for your new `season` column.

```
df['season'] = df.apply(lambda x: f"{x['year']-1}/{x['year']}" if x['month'] <= 3 else f"{x['year']}/{x['year']+1}", axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  year_month  year  month     season
0    2007-01  2007      1  2006/2007
1    2009-07  2009      7  2009/2010
2    2010-03  2010      3  2009/2010
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!